# Why does DataGridView loses header indexes after we add a DataGridViewImageColumn?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple DataGridView and it is filled from database data.

I added a last column, a DataGridViewImageColumn. Everything ok, I see the image at last column, but if I click on first column in my gridView, it orders by second column data, if I click on last column header, it orders by first column data.

Why it get messed after add a column?
I spent hours googling that, but no luck.

Please can you guys explain this problem and show some fix for that?

Here is the event handler to listen click on the gridView headers and tell us what index the column has.

```
private void gridViewHeaderClickHandler(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Index: "+ e.ColumnIndex);
        //after added the image column, if I click on first header 
        //column, it says Index: 1 instead 0
    }
```

Bellow the gridView code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
   adapter.Fill(dt);
}

gridView.DataSource = dt;
gridView.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = '-';
gridView.AutoResizeColumns();

gridView.Columns[0].HeaderText = "ID";
gridView.Columns[0].Width = 60;
gridView.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;

gridView.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;
gridView.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Item";
gridView.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

gridView.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Label 1";
gridView.Columns[2].Width = 170;
gridView.Columns[2].ReadOnly = true;
gridView.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "R$ 0.00";

gridView.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Label 2";
gridView.Columns[3].Width = 170;
gridView.Columns[3].ReadOnly = true;
gridView.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "R$ 0.00";

gridView.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Label 3";
gridView.Columns[4].Width = 100;
gridView.Columns[4].ReadOnly = true;
```

At this point, all gridView headers have accordinally its indexes 0,1,2,3,4 and we can see when we click each of them using event handler method as shown before. Then we create a last column (image column, but button column has same problem)...

```
//Createing an Image Column
DataGridViewImageColumn imgCol = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
imgCol.Image = listImgBars[0];
imgCol.Width = 45;
gridView.Columns.Insert(5, imgCol);
```

Now, the gridView headers changed it's indexes. First column has index 1 instead 0, last column (image) has index 0 instead having 5. Why that?

I know we can make some workaround, but the is always better to know the source problem and to code of the best form possible.

-
Thank you all for your time helping with that!

Comment: I'm not seeing an issue with the code you have posted. Can you add any other code related to your DataGridView?

Comment: Hey @eclecticist, thanks for checking that. I've edited the post.

Comment: Instead of Inserting  you could Add the new Column. You can still set its DisplayIndex to move it around.. But: I do not see what you described. So there must be something else going on in your code..!

Comment: I tried useing .Add too, but the problem is still there. I am using metro grid view, but tried using the base class data grid vew too. That's weird, maybe my .net framework version? In meantime I am using a little workaround, placing an column index correction factor in my class when needed. Thanks for checking that!